# Why do we daven for what has already been promised?

Tags: tefilla, yom-kippur

In the davening of Yom Kippur we ask "ואל תפר בריתך אתנו" that Hashem should not annul his covenant with us (cf page 682 of the Artscroll machzor). But on page 680, we had just read a quote from [Vayikra](https://www.sefaria.org/Leviticus.26.44?lang=bi&aliyot=0) 26:44 which says

> וְאַף־גַּם־זֹ֠את בִּֽהְיוֹתָ֞ם בְּאֶ֣רֶץ אֹֽיְבֵיהֶ֗ם לֹֽא־מְאַסְתִּ֤ים וְלֹֽא־גְעַלְתִּים֙ לְכַלֹּתָ֔ם לְהָפֵ֥ר בְּרִיתִ֖י אִתָּ֑ם
>
> Yet, even then, when they are in the land of their enemies, I will not reject them or spurn them so as to destroy them, annulling My covenant with them:

So we have the textual promise that something *will never happen* and yet we pray that it won't happen. To my mind, this is different from asking that something promised TO happen will happen sooner rather than later, or that something that might not happen will happen.

Doesn't this reflect a lack of belief Ch"V in Hashem's promise?

Comment: To my knowledge, the brit can be temporarily annulled if Israel acts sinfully -- the promise from Hashem is that He will never _completely_ annul the brit. When Israel starts acting righteously again, He renews it.